# MySQL connection pool is exceeding max number of connections in Java

Tags: java, mysql

I have a remote MySQL database. In Java, I have a connection pool:

```
pool = new MysqlConnectionPoolDataSource();
pool.setURL("jdbc:mysql://1.2.3.4:3306/TEST?max-connections=100");
pool.setUser("USER");
pool.setPassword("PASSWORD");
```

The max number of connections is 100. Now let's make 100 threads:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 100; ++i) {
    Thread t = new Thread(new Client(i, pool));
    t.start();
}
```

And this is the code running in each thread:

```
class Client implements Runnable {
    int id;
    MysqlConnectionPoolDataSource pool;
    public Client(int id, MysqlConnectionPoolDataSource pool) {
        this.id = id;
        this.pool = pool;
    }
    public void run() {
        while (true) {
            try {
                Connection conn = pool.getConnection();
                ResultSet set = conn.createStatement().executeQuery("SELECT * FROM SOMETHING");
                if (set.next()) {
                    System.out.println(id + " finished.");
                }
                set.close();
                conn.close();
                return;
            }catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("ERROR " + id + "  ->  " + e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So, I have a pool with 100 max connections, and then 100 threads trying to use one connection each.

And yet, there are several errors of the form:

> ERROR 30  ->  User already has more than 'max_user_connections' active connections

But why, if the max number of connections is 100?

In fact, even if you change it to

```
pool.setURL("jdbc:mysql://1.2.3.4:3306/TEST?max-connections=300");
```

The problem persists.

Of course, eventually, the connection is made and I can perform the query. But I don't understand why am I supposedly exceeding the number of connections.

Comment: NB You are leaking connections in the error case, and statements in all cases.

Answer (score 3):

`max_user_connections` is a *server* setting in `my.ini`: see [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/user-resources.html). It has nothing to do with the connection pool, Java, etc.

Answer (score 3):

Unless you're an application server vendor, you shouldn't be using **MysqlConnectionPoolDataSource**.

`ConnectionPoolDataSources` are **not** connection pools. They are *vendors* of connections to connection pooling code. Besides creating those physical connections a `ConnectionPoolDataSource` shouldn't do anything else.

In any case, the physical connection does not go away until you call `PooledConnection.close()`, calling `conn.close()` only closes the *logical* connection, which requires that any listeners on the `ConnectionPoolDataSource` be called so that it can **reclaim** but not close the physical connection so that it can be handed out again

So if you are working in an application server, use the pooling provided by the `DataSources` of the application server

If you need a standalone connection pool use third party connection pools like BoneCP, c3p0 or Apache DBCP